# Invalid server certificate when trying to upload to app store

Tags: ios, xcode

The error I get when I click Next in Xcode after it displays login info is:
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

I am using Xcode ver 5.1.1
The screenshot is attached

[image]

Edit:
Can any one pls. try to login using Application Loader or Xcode now and let me know if it works for you. If possible pls share the screenshot. I am completely stuck.
Created a new mac admin account and that also results in same issue.

Comment: Could you execute this command line and provide what you get? openssl s_client -connect contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com:443

Comment: Its long output.Here is the end part of that SSL handshake has read 4543 bytes and written 440 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-MD5
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: F31D4FF60A232F4F24D0D8290B9F6CCAB77BD4D28F9D018152930F2F51523B9B972725D92C65EC5CCF350F1E02081DE7
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1415961060
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's really only the certificate you can try opening the URL with Safari (Firefox won't help, Chrome probably works as well):
https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com
That should pop up a similar warning, but this time you have the option to trust the server. Once done, that will be valid for Xcode as well, as it's saved in the keychain.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the date and time. the date & time the year was incorrect. You need to fix it.

You can do so by:

```
settings>general>date & time>set date & time
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:

```
Go to Preferences, Advanced, select DAV only.

This will use port 443 (aka HTTPS) for uploading.
```

Comment: This didn't help. Could it be related to some ssl or port 443 settings somewhere in my mac.

Comment: Yes DAV is already selected. I had applied security update https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6531 on Nov 1. The URL mentions something about SSL. Can I fix something related that security update.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Xcode 5.1.1

Which Mac OS X are you on? It might actually help upgrading both OS and Xcode

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5429834?start=0&tstart=0
(Don't know if this is the same issue, but looks similar)

I see in the comments for the above answer that you have already checked, but **double-check** that the year, month, day, and time is correct. This is the most common mistake

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4912924

EDIT: Also make sure you have the Apple CA and other certificates:

https ://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/